# Trouble understanding what RE.findall() is doing here

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get my arms around Python RE module. However, I am having a hard time why python3 thinks findall() has two matches...

```
>>>import re
>>>re.match('\d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{1,4}', '123-345--0987')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='123-345'>
>>>re.search('\d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{1,4}', '123-345--0987')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='123-345'>
>>>re.findall('\d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{1,4}', '123-345--0987')
['123-345', '0987']
```

I would have thought that findall() call would not match 0987? What am I missing?

Comment: it's because your pattern doesn't take in account the two consecutive hyphens. Since all hyphens are optional, a second match is found.

Comment: See e.g. https://regex101.com/r/oB2hX5/1

Comment: Thanks for the link Casimir. I guess I was not clear in my question. Why is the regex pattern given to `findall()` even matching 0987??

Comment: Oops, sorry about that Casimir. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>>re.findall('\d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{1,4}', '123-345--0987')
['123-345', '0987']
```

Why?

Because `\d{1,3}` matches a digit ranges from 1 to 3 **greedily**. Since it's greedy, it tries to match the largest possible thing so, `123-345` got matched and the following `--` is failed to match because of the double dashes. Then it tries to find a match from the remaining string , so `0987` got matched - `"09" matched by \d{1,3}` , `"8" matched by \d{1,3}`  and `"7" matched by \d{1,4}`.

```
123-345--0987   \d{1,3}
```

At first `\d{1,3}` tries to match all the three digits greedily. If no three digits are found , then it tries to match 2 digits , then one digit. Because the above pattern in greedy, it matches `123`, `345` and `098`

```
123-345--0987   \d{1,3}[-\s]?
```

Then it tries to match the following optional `-` or space. So `123-`, `345-`, `098` got matched.

```
123-345--0987   \d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{1,3}
```

It matches `123-345` and `0987` it matches and extra `7` in the second because you defined `\d{1,3}` matches the digits ranges from 1 to 3 (*Backtracking occurs here*).

```
123-345--0987   \d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{1,3}[-\s]?
```

`[-\s]?` Matches an optional space character or dash. Now this matches `123-345-` and `0987` remains as it is. Because this pattern is an optional one.

```
123-345--0987   \d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{1,3}[-\s]?\d{1,4}
```

In-order to provide an match, all greedily matched `123-345` backtracks one-step and the `5` in `123-345` is matched by the last `\d{1,4}` pattern. Note that it, drops the `-` in the previously matched  `123-345-` because there isn't a digit after the `5-`. Now, take the second match, ie `0987`. We already got a match but in-order to provide a match , `\d{1,4}` matches the last `7`, and the `\d{1,3}` pattern which exists before `[-\s]?\d{1,4}` matches `8` . Backtracking occurs here.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for clarifying that Avinash. Quick follow up: `>>> re.findall('\d{1,3}[-\s]{1}\d{1,3}[-\s]{1}\d{1,4}', '123-345--0987')` returns `[]`. Why would this be blank? I would have thought it would at least return `['123-345']`

Comment: because of double dashes. try `re.findall('\d{1,3}[-\s]{1}\d{1,3}[-\s]{2}\d{1,4}', '123-345--0987')`